# Buscar posição anterior e duas posições atrás em laço for

Tags: c#

Dentro de um laço `for`, eu preciso pegar o valor anterior da variável `i` e o valor anterior ao anterior. Veja, subtrair a variável de -1 e -2, não funciona. Isso não é pegar duas ou uma posição anterior, mas sim subtrair o valor atual de 1 ou 2. O que quero é a sequência de Fibonacci, mas peço que ninguém me envie código pronto, apenas se há alguma forma de pegar esses valores da forma como eu falei. Gostaria de eu mesmo montar a lógica e o código.

```
public List<int> fibonacci(int fim)
{
    List<int> lista = new List<int>();

    int r = 0;
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < fim; i++ )
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            r = 0;
            lista.Add(r);
        }
        else
        {
            if (i == 1)
                r = 1;
            else
                r = r ==>> Aqui que estou apanhando

            lista.Add(r);

            x = r;
        }

    }
    return lista;
}
```

Comment: Terá de explicar melhor porque é que subtrair 1 e 2 não funciona.

Comment: Coloque o código de como você está fazendo, as vezes é algum erro na lógica pro `-1` e `-2` não funcionar

Comment: é sequencia de fibonacci. Tipo na posição 3 de I eu teria I -1 = 2 + I - 2 = 1, isso daria 3 e deveria ser 2, porque fibonacci é: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13.... Veja que I-1 e I-2 não daria certo.

Comment: Porque você não declara duas variáveis `anterior` e `anteriorDoAnterior`?

Comment: De que ponto você inicia o laço? Do zero?

Comment: do 0, vou editar a pergunta e postar meu código.

Comment: A sugestão do @VictorStafusa acho bem viável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi assim. Um colega de outro fórum me postou esse algoritmo:

> 1 - Declarar uma variável inteira com o nome da (a), iniciando em 0;
> 2
>   - Declarar uma variável inteira com o nome de (b), iniciando em 1;
> 3 - Criar um laço com a variável inteira (i), começando em 0, até o número
>   final que deseja calcular.
> 4 - Declarar uma variável inteira
>   temporária (temp) dentro do laço, e atribuir o valor da primeira
>   variável (a).
> 5 - Redeclarar a variável (a) com o conteúdo da variável
>   (b)
> 6 - Redeclarar a variável (b) com o conteúdo da variável (temp)
>   somado ao conteúdo da variável (b)
> 7 - Exibir o valor da variável (a)

Aí fiz isso:

```
public List<int> fibonacci(int fim)
        {
            List<int> lista = new List<int>();

            int a = 0;
            int b = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < fim-1; i++ )
            {
                int x = a;

                a = b;

                b = x + b;

                lista.Add(a);

            }

            return lista;
        }
```

Sugestão também do @VictorStafusa (duas variáveis, exatamente como ele sugeriu).

Comment: Marque essa resposta como certa se resolveu o seu problema.

Comment: Só posso marcar depois de dois dias, pois o post foi meu.

Answer (score 1):

O @Maicon tem razão que, provavelmente, você está só errando um índice.

Se você quer fazer isso sem índices, você pode criar um [`IEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx). O construtor (digamos, da `LookBehindEnumerator`) aceitaria um `Enumerator` (no caso, os termos iniciais da sequência de Fibonacci) e o número de termos pra olhar para trás (no caso dois). O construtor é responsável por ler os primeiros N termos do enumerador e guardar numa variável-membro (que seria o “histórico” da sequência).

O `MoveNext` pegaria o próximo termo da sequência, concatenaria ao histórico, descartaria o histórico, e retornaria o histórico atual.

O loop que for consumir a saída desse `IEnumerator` receberia não um `int`, mas uma `List<int>`, e aí o seu Fibonacci simplesmente usaria a lista de dois elementos como resultado para colocar mais um termo na mesma lista (eu imagino que se você adicionar os novos termos na lista, o `foreach` vai rodar infinitamente, inclusive; você teria que ter uma condição de parada *ou* usar o Fibonacci apenas como um enumerator.

Eu não sei quanto código eu devo botar na minha resposta, já que você quer fazer sozinho, mas a assinatura do tipo seria algo tipo:

```
class LookBehindEnumerator<IEnumerator<T> TEnumerator, int WindowSize> : IEnumerator<List<T>>
```

Comment: (fui vago demais?)

Comment: Não necessariamente. Mas acho que implementar o algorítmo de fibonacci não deveria ser tão complexo assim, pois qualquerempresa hoje pede como teste no papel a implementação desse algorítmo. Eu estou apenas treinando soluções mais rápidas. Percebi aolongo da minha caminhada que tenho despendido tempo demais em coisas simples e por isso estou estudando,para ter as coisas mais presentes em minha mente.

Comment: Não entendi os dois downvotes que recebi. O que está errado na minha pergunta? Como sempre tenho falado, tem uns caras aqui se acham os tais. Senão for do jeito deles não serve. Só pedi que não me enviasse códigos, será isso quebra do regulamento?